# Remove the tag [osgi-bundle] and merge it into [osgi]

Tags: feature-request, retag-request

The way it is used on the site today, the tag [osgi-bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osgi-bundle) does not add any extra meaning over simply using the tag [osgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osgi). Can we remove [osgi-bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osgi-bundle) and merge it into [osgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osgi)?

Tag queries:

```
[osgi]                = 3072 questions
[osgi-bundle]         =  259 questions
[osgi-bundle] -[osgi] =   72 questions
```